# Why does the ratio test fail for finding the interval of convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Does it have to do with how ratio test is inconclusive when the ratio is $1$?

I ask the question because I've always just been told "ratio test for the radius of convergence" and then I have to do the endpoints separately for the interval of convergence (by putting in those specific values of $x$) -- but I've never really been told why this is really necessary.

I know the ratio test converges when $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<1$ and diverges when it's greater than $1$ and it's inconclusive when it's $1$... so I'm wondering if the reason why ratio tests fails at endpoints is because the test is inconclusive there?

Comment: I think we're going to need more context, the ratio test is often a very useful tool for finding the interval of convergence but its usefulness depends on the series.

Comment: I added to the original question. Unfortunately, I'm talking about the general case so the question might not be answerable.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. It's exactly as you said: your endpoints are where the ratio in the ratio test goes to $1$, so the ratio test doesn't give you any information about the convergence at those points. A good example is the convergence of $f(x) = \Sigma \dfrac{x^n}{n}$.